# How to get bold greek letters and brackets using latex2exp package?

Tags: r, latex, expression, symbols, equation

I'm using the `latex2exp` package to create some equations that will be placed on plots or on the axes. Despite using the `bold = TRUE` option within the arguments of the `TeX()` function, the Greek letters and brackets do not appear in bold. Would anyone know how I can get this formatting?

**Additional help:** It appears that math operators like `+` and `=` are also not rendered in bold when I try to put space between terms in the equation.

```
library(latex2exp)

Equation1 <- TeX(r"($\left(\frac{\mu}{\beta^2}\right) + constant$)",
                bold = TRUE)

Equation2 <- TeX(r"($\left(\frac{\mu}{\beta^2}\right)+constant$)",
                 bold = TRUE)

plot(Equation1)
plot(Equation2)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also the `italic = TRUE` argument seems to have no effect on the Greek characters.